# google compute engine and vm reboot

Tags: google-compute-engine

Elementary question but I don't want to take any chances. We have several Google Compute Engine VM's running Windows Server 2016. As of this morning, the application on one VM is experiencing issues - the only thing to change that I can see is the installation of Windows Updates. I want to reboot the VM before doing additional trouble shooting. Typically I would just RDP to the VM and do a Start | Power | Restart. Is this OK in the Google environment or is there a better way to accomplish it? We have a static ip address for the application.

Answer (score 0):

[Performing a reset on your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#resetting_an_instance) is similar to doing a hard reset on your computer where you might press a reset button or press and hold the power button. Resetting an instance forcibly wipes the memory contents of the machine and resets the virtual machine to its initial state. The instance does not perform a clean shutdown of the guest OS. Throughout this process, the instance remains in `RUNNING` state.

When you reset an instance, none of the instance properties change. The instance retains its ephemeral IP address, its persistent disk, its machine type, etc. However, any data stored in memory is reset unless you back up the data.

Please check the [following documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/instance-life-cycle#comparison_table) to know the implications of each state of your VM Instances.

Also you can take a look at the [Instance Life Cycle](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/instance-life-cycle)